# How should we pass event handlers to custom hooks without useEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm reading through the new docs and I've come across this section on [Passing event handlers to custom Hooks](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#passing-event-handlers-to-custom-hooks) which explains an issue of rerenders.

> Adding a dependency on onReceiveMessage is not ideal because it will cause the chat to re-connect every time the component re-renders. Wrap this event handler into an Event function to remove it from the dependencies.

This makes sense, but the solution proposes `useEvent` which has now been dropped.

**Question:** what is the current convention for dealing with this? Do we just have to wrap the event in `useCallback` from the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we just have to wrap the event in useCallback from the component?

Yes. Memoize `onReceiveMessage` so that it doesn't get re-created unless absolutely necessary. For example, instead of

```
export default function ChatRoom({ roomId }) {
  const [serverUrl, setServerUrl] = useState('https://localhost:1234');

  useChatRoom({
    roomId: roomId,
    serverUrl: serverUrl,
    onReceiveMessage(msg) {
      showNotification('New message: ' + msg);
    }
  });
  // ...
```

do

```
export default function ChatRoom({ roomId }) {
  const [serverUrl, setServerUrl] = useState('https://localhost:1234');
  const onReceiveMessage = useCallback((msg) => {
    showNotification('New message: ' + msg);
  }, [showNotification]);
  useChatRoom({
    roomId,
    serverUrl,
    onReceiveMessage
  });
  // ...
```

where `showNotification` is also made to be as stable a reference as possible (if it's something that comes from React state/props).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the example and clarification. It's a bummer they dropped the `useEvent` RFC.